# How to interact with the elements inside iframe. But iframe is within two shadow DOM's in cypress

Tags: javascript, iframe, automated-tests, cypress, shadow-dom

I am unable to interact with elements inside shadow DOM and iframe. Attached is the HTML document snippet. I am using cypress here. I am directly interacting with the second shadow DOM and then the iframe.

My cypress code

```
cy.get('formbuilder-mainpage').should(e => {
  console.log(e)
  const [dom] = e.get()
  console.log(dom)
  dom.shadowRoot.querySelector().getIframe('iframe').find('New Organization').click()

})
```

[image: HTML Doc]

Answer (score 0):

In your cypress config file, add `includeShadowDom: true`, this will make sure that all the cypress commands will automatically traverse Shadow DOMS.

For iFrame's I owuld suggest you use the plugin [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) plugin.

```js
cy.iframe('iframe').('elmeent-selector').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Cypress commands, the following could be your test.

First, `.notification-toast` is a toat popup, which will be animated so include the  `.layout-wrapper` below it and Cypress will wait for animation to finish.

```js
it('test deeply nested shadow DOM', () => {

  cy.get('main .notification-toast .layout-wrapper')           
    .shadow()                                              // 1st shadow
    .find('formbuilder-mainpage')
    .shadow()                                              // 2nd shadow
    .getIframe('iframe')
    .find('New Organization')
    .click()
})
```